# How to hang up after key press or after a minute with twilio?

Tags: php, xml, twilio

I am trying to make an application with twilio. The overall functionality is that a user is going to call into a system, and right away be presented with a voice menu to either press 1 through 9 or hang up. Is there a way to make twilio disconnect the call (and pass me the keypress) as soon as the user presses a digit (I don't want them to have to press #)? If they don't press anything, I want to hang up after a minute and the system would pass me something that says they pressed nothing.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could accomplish this with the following TwiML:

```
<Response>
    <Gather numDigits="1" action="keypressed.php">
         <Pause length="60" />
    </Gather>
    <Redirect method="GET">nokeypressed.php</Redirect>
</Response>
```

In each `keypressed.php` and `nokeypressed.php` you would respond accordingly.

[<Gather> Hints and Advanced Uses](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/2010-04-01/twiml/gather#hints)

Comment: You might also be able to use timeout="60" on the <Gather>, but I can't recall how that interacts with numDigits="1"

Comment: Ok cool, thanks for the help. And can I put the <say> in the gather and have <pause> in the say so that the message will play while the timer is going?

Comment: You could put the <Say> in the <Gather>, then the <Pause> *after* the <Say> (you can't nest a Pause in a Say) but then shorten the length to compensate for the length of the spoken text.

Comment: ahh ok, that makes sense... and then after the pause I can just hang up. Thanks!